# How do I earn reputation points the fastest?

Tags: discussion

So I've got 15-ish years of exp on everything webdev/js/ts, but no reputation. I see questions asked where I would really be able to contribute with a good answer but I can't because ... no reputation points.

What is the fastest way to earning reputation ?
(because I literally don't have at my disposal the time to "work my way up")

Thank you in advance people.

Comment: "*I see questions asked where I would really be able to contribute with a good answer but I can't because ... no reputation points.*" ... No, that's not true as you can post an answer on most questions (excluding protected) ... You just did that below ... So, help if you can and reputation shall come.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As has been pointed out, the fastest way to gain reputation if you have relevant knowledge is to answer questions - this doesn't require any reputation unless the question is 'protected'. If you want to answer a protected question, please do let us know (with some why and what kinda details) so we can unprotect it to allow you to answer. Sometimes people come here with the kind of complaint you've written because they are trying to *comment* on posts, rather than answer. Commenting requires 50 reputation (a restriction supposed to prevent misuse), but ...

Comment: ... we don't attach much value to comments, compared to questions and answers. If what you are trying to do is post comments, please consider posting answers instead.

Comment: By the way, as you probably noticed, you don't get any reputation for votes on meta posts :)

Answer (score 7):

You can answer most questions with no reputation. In addition, some high-volume questions are [protected](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), but as far as I know, it only takes 10 reputation to answer these.

So here are some advice:

- Just provide good questions and answers - each upvote on a question or answer will give you 10 reputation
- You can also suggest edits to existing questions and answers - each accepted edit will give you 2 reputation.
- Don't expect to take any shortcuts - the only reliable way to gain rep is to contribute with quality content

Here are two examples of behavior that will NOT gain you any reputation:

> (because I literally don't have at my disposal the time to "work my way up")

> please up-vote !

Also, why would you think you're special, and the normal rules for reputation should not apply to you? I'm just curious.

Answer (score -6):

So apparently one way to earning reputation is to answer my on questions ?!!?!
How will that help, of course ... i'll keep you posted.

please up-vote !

thank you in advance people !

notes:
upon posting answers they will give you some pointers on how to respond .... well, that's not bad as a method to take in the community standards in an organic way ...
let's see how it works out !

Comment: The way to lose any reputation you may have already acquired is to beg for upvotes...